# Get checkbox value in angular2+ (not using ngModel )

Tags: angular

How can I get checkbox value without using ngModel (cause I don't want to declare field variable for every checkbox)

when code be like :

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="foo(bar)">
```

and

```
public foo(bar) {
    console.log(bar);
}
```

Expected output is `true` or `false` (whatever that shows checkbox status)

Comment: Both answers bellow are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input #bar type="checkbox" (click)="foo(bar.checked)">
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2nw64?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="foo($event.target.checked)">
```